# single linked list java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
System.out.println("insert after specified data node");
System.out.println("enter data");
int x = sc.nextInt();
Node s4 = head;
try
{
    while(s4.data != x)
    {
        s4 = s4.next;
    }
}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("hi");

Node specifiedNode = new Node(x);
//s4.next = specifiedNode;

try
{
    specifiedNode.next = s4.next;
    s4.next = specifiedNode;

}
catch(NullPointerException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("output after specified insertion");
Node s5 = head;
while(s5!=null)
{
    System.out.println(s5.data);
    s5 = s5.next;
}
```

}

This is the sample program to insert data after a specified node in single linked list. In the above program my question is why null pointer exception is happening at the following statements:

```
specifiedNode.next = s4.next;
s4.next = specifiedNode;
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: You need to write and draw what you are trying to accomplish. This implementation is way off.

Comment: `while(s4.data != x) s4 = s4.next;`  So basicly, if you don't have `x` in that list, it fails... You should not catch NPE but manage them. For the _"why?"_, have you just check the value ?

Answer (score 0):

why do you keep accessing the .next of the s4 instance?
the way to do that is to store the s4.next in an attribute for one time and keep using it in all your program since each time you access the .next() you are invoking the next record and probably one of them is null;

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid a NullPointerException, ensure you always check on `s4` not being null.

```
Node s4 = head;      // Head initially is null (empty list).
while (s4 != null) { // End reached?
    if (s4.data == x) {
        // Wow, found x.
        break; // Jump out of the loop.
    }

    // Go to next node.
    s4 = s4.next; // s4 could become null.
}
```